# JDK extraction and installation error issues on windows 10

Tags: java

I got this error while extracting JDK to program files folder [cannot create jdk 13... The system cannot find the path specified. (This error is upto 597 error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P34K.jpg) 
So I extracted the file to another folder and followed the required steps to install JDK, that is going to environment variables and I copied the path and all of that. Went to the command prompt to confirm the installation, and to error occurred

1. Unrecognised option version
2. Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Comment: I’m not sure what steps you’re following.  If you download the JDK as a zip file, successfully unzipping it, to any directory of your choice, is the only step needed.  If you’re getting other errors, please edit your question and show us the exact command you’re entering and the exact text of the error.

Comment: Please provide screenshot (**Prt Scr** on keyboard and paste it in Paint or any image editor). Mointor images snapped from cameras are difficult to read.